# Laravels's Eloquent "create" method tries to save empty attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
class Setting extends Eloquent {
    public $primaryKey = 'key';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $fillable = array('*');
}
```

My table `settings` consists of 2 columns: `key` and `value`.

When I try to execute:

```
Setting::create(array(
    'key' => 'test',
    'value'=> 'test1'
));
```

I get:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into`settings`() values ()) (Bindings: array ( ))`

which is extremely weird. Any ideas? I tried this on 2 tables, it has the same problem. My Laravel version is up to date.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to save?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show you database table definition. Are you sure that 'key' is really set as PRIMARY key in your table? The first thing came to my mind is that you probably have different field set as PRIMARY in your 'settings' table ('id' or something) and you didn't set 'auto_increment' flag for that field.